# Element moves up during animation cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a little issue with one of my elements that I'm animating, it's moving up slightly during animation. It moves up maybe 2-3 pixels while the anim is playing then snaps back down when the it's done.

The element in question is a search field, it works similar to what stackoverflow has on this very page (look on top of this page in the header bar and click on the search field). The field's width increases when the user clicks on it. Mine jumps up as it does that.

I've created a fiddle with my exact code, however I can't get it to run in there, the code is correct I just think I'm using the fiddle incorrectly to load the jQuery.

Here is it: https://jsfiddle.net/vanillasnake21/4gLdaxqr/

HTML for reference of layout:

```
<div id="minimenu"> 
<a href="#"> inquire </a> 
<a href="#">social</a> 
<a href="#">feedback</a>
<a href="#">forum</a>
<a href="#"> customer login</a>
<div id="search" class="search_nominal">
        <button id ="search_button" class="search_button_nominal"> </button>
         <input id="search_field" class="search_field_nominal" type="text"placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

> edit: ok I think the jfiddle is not working because I'm using jqueryui switchClass, which I believe is not supported. I'll rewrite it right now.
>
> edit 2: After rewriting switchClass with with .removeClass.addClass, the problem went away, apparently that function adds some additional effects to the transitions.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by dropping the switchClass method I was using (a part of jQuery UI) and instead switched to the regular .removeClass("class).addClass("class) implementation and the jitter went away.